# Docker inspect format retrieve port mapping

Tags: docker

I'd like to retrieve the port mapped to a container using docker inspect, I found something like that:

```
docker inspect --format=" {{ .NetworkSettings.Ports }} " containerid
```

Output:

```
map[1234/tcp:[map[HostIp:0.0.0.0 HostPort:49159]] 3306/tcp:<nil> 4444/tcp:<nil> 4567/tcp:<nil> 4568/tcp:<nil>]
```

But I'd like to have an output like this:

```
1234/tcp:49159
```

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 28):

The `docker port` command may be more useful; it produces output like this:

```
$ docker port 0a7b4df54966
443/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:4430
80/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8888
```

Comment: Great I didn't know about docker port

Answer (score 8):

You can use index in your template:

```
--format '1234/tcp:{{ (index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "1234/tcp") 0).HostPort }}'
```

Comment: Specifically, `--format '{{ (index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "1234/tcp") 0).HostPort }}'`