# Start Docker container with random host port and return the port to use it elsewhere

Tags: github, jenkins, docker

I want to start a docker container with ,let's say jenkins as a service, and let docker allocate a random host port. I know how to do this .

How can I grab the randomly selected port from the running container, or tell docker to return it, in order to use it in the construction of the jenkins github plugin url

```
http://host-ip:random-host-port/web-hook
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the docker run -P is done, the container is running, [with the EXPOSE(d) port mapped to an high port number on the host](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/usingdocker/#viewing-our-web-application-container).

To get any information on a running container, use **[`docker inspect`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/inspect/)**.

If you know the container internal port number (that was then mapped), you can type ([from this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30646242/docker-inspect-format-retrieve-port-mapping#comment49357940_30646912)):

```
 docker inspect --format '{{ (index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "8080/tcp") 0).HostPort }}' <Container-Name/ID>
```

The [offical Jenkins image uses `EXPOSE 8080`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/9395d3fdd74cd43f03b1844fbb0c3e48d713cbc1/Dockerfile#L42).

Comment: Thank you very much VonC, I will inspect further the 'docker inspect' command and the info it provides.

Comment: Thanks VonC , it works exactly as I wanted. Maybe you would like to add 'Container-Name/ID' in the end of the command for clarification.

Comment: @KostasDemiris True, I have edited the answer accordingly.